# How to debug a boot loader?

Tags: debugging, bootloader, grub

I debugged small programs using gdb.

I have source code of GRUB. Second stage of GRUB is written in C.
Can I debug it using gdb ?

Is it possible to debug a boot loader ?
If yes, then how ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. I would check out [bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/)
2. You can also use [gdb with bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/doc/docbook/user/debugging-with-gdb.html)
3. [OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org) has a wealth of information on debugging a bootloader